# How to setup length in search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have search box connected to mysql database.

I'am trying to set the min charchters in search box to be 3 letters to start a search, but I want it at the same time accept search by these two letters "th" together.

I'm trying to setup the length like that but it doesnt work!
    Here is my code:

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  var minlength=3;
  if(search != '') {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      load_data(search);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another condition:

```
if (search != "" && (search.startsWith("th") || search.length >= minlength)) {...}
```

Comment: I should add your name to the contributors part of the code :D works like a charm, thanks

Comment: That's no problem @jason5137715, I am always glad to help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm limiting the min letters because it's a big database, for security reason so no one can flood the search function, But I'm curious if I setup time between each search like 5 seconds between each subment is it enough or I should add google captcha? :)

Comment: I think a captcha would be fine - it would make your engine faster because people don't have to wait 5 seconds if they spell something wrong.

Comment: I forget about that, good point, okay I will add a captcha :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'th' together - should 'th' just be counted as one letter?

For the min length, you can check like this:

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  var minlength = 3;
    if (event.key === "Enter" && search.length >= minlength) {
      load_data(search);
    }
  });
});
```

If you wanted to count 'th' as one letter:

```
var count = (search.match(/th/g) || []).length // returns no. of occurrences of 'th'
var totalCount = search - count
```